# Can't add the converter while binding

Tags: c#, xaml, converters

I've implemented the interface *IValueConverter* as shown [here](http://www.tewari.info/2008/04/15/using-custom-converter-in-xaml/) and I put it **for now** in the same file as my code-behind to the XAML (two classes, both in the same namespace but implementing *IValueConverter* and inheriting *Window*).

```
public class BamseGurka : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) { ... }
  public object ConvertBack(object v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) { ... }
}
```

In XAML I added a label, the visibility of which is bound to the outcome that need to be converted, as shown [here - "how to use value converter in XAML"](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

```
<Label Name="ErrorMessage" ...
       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BamseConverter}}" >
```

Since I'll want to use a **really** custom converter and not one that's been forseen by Microsoft (no booleans, integers or such), I need to refer my implementation (as opposed to e.g. *BoolToVisibilityConverter*). I hoped that the intellisense would give me good suggestion on the matter but I ended up in adding a resource to the parent element (or window, or application) like so.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <ComboCellBindingConverter x:Key="BamseConverter" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

And this raises two issues - first of all why do I get (and what is) *ComboCellBindingConverter*. And secondly, what am I supposed to put there instead (since that symbol can't be resolved and I need to point to **my** implementation anyway)?

Being sneaky, I tried to circumvent as follows but that only led to the same error.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <BamseGurka x:Key="BamseConverter" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Using the intellisense, I arrived at a new attribute in the window tag and the following setup.

```
xmlns:blopp="clr-namespace:The.Actual.Namespace" ...

<StackPanel.Resources>
  <blopp:BamseGurka x:Key="BamseConverter" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Now, it complains about *BamseGurka* not being in the mentioned namespace, which is a bold lie because it is! And just for fun, when I switched *BamseGurka* for the name of the original class (the other one in the same file, remember?), the error was gone.

So I'm kind of at a loss here. Haven't used custom converters like this before. Suggestions? Google gave me a lot to go on if *DataContext* is *null* but nother better when it comes to converters.

Comment: Could post a reproducible example? The last solution should be working (Referencing the Converter in the Resources with the correct namespace) - Sometimes the wpf designer needs a build/rebuild in order to work properly...

Comment: It'll be hard to post a working example as it's a part of a much bigger solution. According to the guides and tutorials I've read, it should work but, since it apparently doesn't, I'm looking for hints on some sneaky gotchas. What do you mean by designer needing to rebuild? Are we talking rebuilding the solution in VS or are you referring to something more? Please elaborate.

Comment: Only building the solution - and like Artur Malendowicz mentioned, you forgot you actual binding property Visibility="{Binding PropertyToBind,  Converter={StaticResource BamseConverter}}"

Answer (score 0):

For example if you put your converter to separate file located in "Converters" folder in root folder, you would register it in dictionary like that:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:BamseGurka.Converters">

    <converters:BamseConverter x:Name="BamseConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then you would just bind to it like you have done:

```
<Label Name="ErrorMessage" ...
       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BamseConverter}}" >
```

of course, remember to set to what property you bind in Visibility, because for this moment it won't work.